# Position of the text changes when I resume my android app

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-4.4-kitkat

I am creating an android app which needs to draw text in canvas. I am drawing that text in a custom view. So the text is drawn in the onDraw() of that custom view using the drawtext() of canvas class.

The issue is that normally the text position perfect. But whenever I press the home button and  again resumes the app the position of that drawn text changes.The issue seems to be coming only for KitKat.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Utility Utility = new Utility();

    canvas.drawCircle((radiusOfCircle + margin), (radiusOfCircle + margin),
            radiusOfCircle, paint);

    endPath.moveTo((2*radiusOfCircle + margin), (radiusOfCircle + margin));
    linePaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    endPath.lineTo(stopX, (radiusOfCircle + margin));
    canvas.drawPath(endPath, linePaint);


    linePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));


    progressPath.moveTo((2*radiusOfCircle + margin),
            (radiusOfCircle + margin));
    progressPath.lineTo(stopOfProgress, (radiusOfCircle + margin));
    canvas.drawPath(progressPath, linePaint); 
    canvas.drawCircle((radiusOfCircle + margin), (radiusOfCircle + margin),
            radiusOfCircle, paint);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(textStrokeWidth);

    int xPos = radiusOfCircle;
     int yPos = (int) ((radiusOfCircle+ margin) - (Utility.heightRatio((progressTextColor.descent() + progressTextColor.ascent()) / 2, context))) ; 

     progressTextColor.setColor(Color.WHITE);
     progressTextColor.setTextSize(Utility.heightRatio(10, context));
     canvas.drawText(circleText, xPos-Utility.heightRatio(3, context), yPos-Utility.heightRatio(1, context), progressTextColor);


}
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: What does your Utility.heightRatio(...) method do? Where do "radiusOfCircle" and "margin" come from?

Comment: The utility is just changing the values depending upon the screen size. Margin is the margin we set and thats hard coded

Comment: if it was in the correct position before, have you thought about clearing your canvas and calling redraw from scratch?